# Which weather on my road? Looking for a spatial weather forecast web service

Tags: web-service, routing, spatio-temporal-data, weather, direction

My friend Bob goes from A to B leaving tomorrow morning at 6:00. There are many direction services that indicates him short, fast and/or cheap routes. Bob does not like to drive under the rain and wants to know which weather is forecast along different routes.

To help him, I would like to develop a web service that enriches existing direction web services and provides him with the "weather profile" of his trip from A to B. Such weather profile could be represented like on the following image (taken from the excellent Norwegian website [www.yr.no](http://www.yr.no/place/France/Provence-Alpes-C%C3%B4te_d%E2%80%99Azur/Marseille/hour_by_hour.html)), except the X axis would be the travel time (or distance):

[image: weather profile in Marseilles]

Do you know if such service (or comparable) already exist?

Do you know some useful weather forecast web services to develop such thing? The requirement would be a service that provides for any location (lon,lat) a forecast (temperature, rain, etc.) for a given date/time.

Comment: Can be developped with GMap cloud layer: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers?hl=fr#WeatherLayer

Comment: see also http://content.stamen.com/weather_weather_everywhere

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The Weather Underground** does this - Road Trip Planner (with Weather)

[image]

http://www.wunderground.com/roadtrip/

Example Route above:
http://www.wunderground.com/roadtrip/?lat=41.17245&lon=-73.34747&zoom=9&type=map&units=metric&dir=1&dir.p0=NYC&dir.d0=2011-03-15&dir.t0=12%3A00&dir.p1=Boston%2C%20Massachusetts&dir.t1=12%3A00&dir.t2=12%3A00&svr=1&svr.opa=70&tfk=0

Snow Warning...
[image: Snow Warning...]

Comment: Also wunderground has an API http://wiki.wunderground.com/index.php/API_-_XML Example http://api.wunderground.com/auto/wui/geo/WXCurrentObXML/index.xml?query=KSFO

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure of anything that already plans routes by weather conditions, but if you were to try to figure it yourself, I would take a look at [NOAA/NWS GIS Data](http://www.nws.noaa.gov/gis/). They have both KMLs and Shapefiles for current weather, forecasts, hurricanes, etc.

Comment: And, after I post I notice that your picture is weather from France. So this might not help. I am looking into if there is something similar on an international basis.